# Show that $A(x_0)$ is not empty, for any $x_0\in E$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ normed space. For $x_0\in E$ we define $A(x_0)=\{f\in E^*;\|f\|\leq\|x_0\|,f(x_0)=\|x_0\|^2\}$. Show that $A(x_0)$ is not empty, for any $x_0\in E$.

I don't know how I start. Can give me any hint, thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the subspace $Z=\{\alpha x_0:\alpha \in K\}$ where $K$ denotes the underlying field.

Now define $f:Z\to K$ by $f(x)=f(\alpha x_0)=\alpha ||x_0||^2$

Now $||f||=\sup_{x\in Z}\dfrac{||f(x)||}{||x||}=\dfrac{\alpha ||x_0||^2}{||x||}=\dfrac{||x_0||||\alpha x_0||}{||x||}=\dfrac{||x_0||||x||}{||x||}=||x_0||$

By Hahn-Banach Theorem $f$ can be extended as $\overline{f}$ from $E$ to $K$ such that $||\overline f||=||f||=||x_0||$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g:\operatorname{Span}(x_0)\to \Bbb R$ given by $g(tx_0)=t\lvert x_0\rvert$ and $p(x)=\lvert x\rvert\cdot\lvert x_0\rvert$. Notice that that $g(x)\le p(x)$.